# How to load dynamic Tabs in ngDialog box in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

[Dynamic Tab Sample File Link --  Not Working](http://plnkr.co/edit/gelWCaKDVF1Z3WDgrSO2?p=preview)

[Static Tab Sample File Link --  Working](http://plnkr.co/edit/NmyCy3XuklyLReam9SSR?p=preview)

```
In NgDialog Tabs Not Showing
```

In above link I added the sample file for ngDialog model with tabs. In index
 page I call the dynamic tab based on array1 value. same thing I did in template1 html file. In index tabs showing correctly based on value.

[image: Index Image]

In Open model button I call the template1 html file there also i did same thing for tabs but it not showing. may i know why tabs not showing while open in ngdialog? and where i did mistake? can any one help me on this..

For Static:

```
 <tabs>
<pane title="Tab1">
  <div>This is the content of the first tab.</div>
</pane>
<pane title="Tab2">
  <div>This is the content of the second tab.</div>
</pane>
```

For Dynamic:

```
  <tabs>
      <subpane array=array1></subpane>
</tabs>
```

Details Getting From:

```
    $scope.array1 = [{
                          "Title": "Tab1",
                          "FileName": "template.html",
                          "Path": "",
                          "SeqNo": 0

                        },
                        {
                          "Title": "Tab2",
                          "FileName": "template1.html",
                          "Path": "",
                          "SeqNo": 1
                        }];
```

Current output:

[image: Current output Image]

Expected Output:

[image: Expected output]

Comment: take look on this, you might get some ideas
http://codepen.io/justd/pen/dPeKEG

Comment: Tabs working fine. but while I call same file in ngDialog that time only its fail.... @Robus

Comment: In static also its works.. But while load dynamic that time only some problem occur..... @Robus

Comment: can u promote my question by giving vote? ... @Robus

Answer (score 1):

The controller in template1.html is "Main". However when you open the dialog, you specified the controller is "test".

```
ngDialog.open({ template: 'template1.html',controller: 'test', className: 'ngdialog-theme-default', data:$scope.obj});
```

But array1 is in "Main" controller, so there's no array1 in "test" controller and no tab to display.

Comment: your correct But even some problem is there.. tab coming but that html value not coming @Nguyen Viet Cuong